# Can I tag data access for manual cache revalidation without using fetch with Next app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, memoization, react-server-components, react-cache

I would like to implement a revalidation endpoint in a Next project with the app router, so I think my options would be `revalidatePath` and `revalidateTag`.

The data access I want revalidated works with a 3rd party library which requests resources from a CMS without a direct invocation of fetch, also I placed the operation inside a React cached function.

I could create an api in Next to hold the data access, then call the api through fetch from the components to leverage the `tag` option that comes bundled with fetch in Next, but I'd like to avoid exposing a public api for this operation.

**Can I tag for manual revalidation a cached React function in Next? In general, is there a way to tag data access operations other then passing the tag option to fetch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing a bit more I realized that the function cached with React.cache is not memoizing at the data cache level, the function still runs (once) with every request (even if invoked multiple times).

I guess the only way to cache the data access operation would be to stick it inside a next api...

---

2024/01/23 edit:

The actual real solution is to use [unstable_cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_cache) and pass `revalidate` and/or `tags` options.

Hopefully this will soon lose the unstable prefix.